# Amazon CloudSearch: Field names cannot contain uppercase letters?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

We're trying to send our company's json data up to Amazon Cloud search for indexing. We were optimistic we'd just be able to send it over as-is, but our attribute names are camelCased and Amazon's Dashboard seems to be indicating that it *only* accepts lowercase letters and numbers.

Do we really have to transform all of our Json data just for Amazon? Why would they enforce this seemngly arbitrary restriction on their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a headache for me when using Cloudsearch too.  Index names do have to all be lowercase.

This issue, along with no support for substring searches (except for starts-with searches) and the inability to sort results case-insensitively, have been the biggest (and most mind-boggling) hurdles to jump.

Comment: It sounds like you and I are experiencing the same headaches. If you need a recommendation for a good OTC migraine pill let me know. Alternatively, if you have a recommendation for a competing cloud search service I would be interested to hear it!